# jQM datepicker not styling properly and datepicker not running $.datepicker({onSelect:function(){}}) properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

**Problem #1**

This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/pwLMr/3/)'s calendar (below) is unstyled properly. Can anyone tell me why? I've been looking at it for hours.

[image]

as compared to this [fiddle's](http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/W4P25/18/) below.

[image]

Both are using the same external files:

1. https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.js
2. https://rawgithub.com/jquery/jquery-ui/1.10.4/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js
3. https://rawgithub.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper/v0.1.1/jquery.mobile.datepicker.css
4. http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js
5. http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css
6. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js

**Problem #2**

The first fiddle runs the below function well

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#date1").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            alert("HAHA");
        }
    });
});
```

whereas the second fiddle does not.

Comment: because simply in the fiddle you're not loading libraries in the order they should be loaded http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/pwLMr/4/. You should always start with jQuery-core, jQM, jQuery-ui, jQ-datepicker.

Comment: @Omar thanks man... that explains... now can anyone figure out why it doesn't alert HAHA on select? http://jsfiddle.net/geoyws/pwLMr/5/